# Mysql： Use time as a condition to limit insert, update and delete actions

Tags: mysql

I want to complete a function that when everyday's 9:00AM to 17:00PM user can  insert, update and delete.

At other times, the above actions are forbidden. After googling, I still don't know how to make it.

Comment: you can easily write code logic for it..which programming language you're using

Comment: If by "user" you mean a "MySQL account" with "privileges", then there is nothing you can do with **GRANT** that is time-dependent. You will have to use something else to restrict access to the database, which could involve using **GRANT** statements. See:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-privileges

Comment: I know it can be sloved by write code logic with programming language,but the question limited by SQL.

Comment: Maybe I can try TRIGGER?

Comment: You can build the logic into the INSERT, but it's going to be limited (I think) to the locale of the MySQL server.